# Custom install with ZFS Root for Neon (newer Plasma w/20.04 base), SDDM not starting up

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, kde-plasma-5

So following [these instructions](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html) to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto ZFS Root, I got [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org) installed (neon-desktop virtual package). Everything seems good, except when I boot up there's no GUI login. I found SDDM wasn't enabled, so I enabled it `systemctl enable sddm`. When I do `systemctl status sddm` it now shows it's Active, running, no errors.

```
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-03-17 23:42:33 PDT; 19min ago
       Docs: man:sddm(1)
             man:sddm.conf(5)
   Main PID: 2103 (sddm)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 76373)
     Memory: 6.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
             └─2103 /usr/bin/sddm

Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Initializing...
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Starting...
Mar 17 23:42:33 darklaptop sddm[2103]: Logind interface found
```

Yet even after I reboot, nothing shows up as a login interface. When I login, and run `startx`, Plasma DE does startup and run fine, everything seems good.

EDIT:
`systemctl get-default` output is `graphical.target`

EDIT2: Some new information. Booting with `nomodeset` kernel parameter has it load up fine on boot. Without that, it just acts as it did previously

Comment: Hello. Can you give us the output of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: Yes, see above, it's `graphical.target`

Comment: @Fanatique any further suggestions?